# Can i Merge some data from 2 Wordpress Database?

Tags: database, wordpress, woocommerce, merge

Good Morning.
I have a question about wordpress Database.

Can i merge a data from a table from one WooCommerce Database to anorher wordpress website?

Example:
I have one WooCommerce website where my users can buy an annually subscription service and renew it every year.

I would need to fill this data information (bought or renewed subscription) on another Wordpress website and database that have the same users, but for a different scope.

Maybe i can use the VAT number like unique ID that i have on both Database.

So, can i merge this data?

Is it possible that when a customer buys or renews a service on my woocommerce the same data is filled in a user's custom field on the other wordpress website?

Answer (score 0):

no that will not work. Data for WooCommerce (subscriptions and orders) is scattered among multiple tables such as posts and postmeta. Merging the tables won't help because you'll also merge data that are not related to subscriptions and orders. You'll also experience a lot of conflicts because the ID numbers will probably exist on the two sites.

If we're talking about subscriptions and orders, I will suggest you use webtoffee import / export suite if you want to move woocommerce data among sites.